# HOW to apply Picard-Lindelöf to demonstrate that there is ONE solution ONLY for a Initial Value Problem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Take for exemple: for $y'= 2\sqrt{y}$ the 0 function and the functions :$ (x-c)^2$.

How can somebody say there infinite solutions for the initial value $y(0)=0$ ?

And how to find out that are there not infinite solutions for $y(1)=1$ ?

I read many time:  use Picard Lindelöf to show the existence and the singularity of a solution, can you teach me on this exemple how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Solution of for $y′=2\sqrt y$ is $y=(ax+b)^2$ becomes $y=(ax)^2$ for $y(0)=0$; a is arbitrary constant; hence infinite solutions.

Comment: For future readers: this answer is completely wrong. Better look at [other ones](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24y%27%3D2%5Csqrt%7By%7D%24&p=1).